# Lynda - PHP Beyond the Basics - Database error when uploading photo

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I searched before writing this question but didn't think I would find a response because my issue is SO specific.

Anyway, I have been following the PHP Beyond the Basics course on Lynda.com by Kevin Skoglund and have run into a snag when it comes to uploading photos to the database (MySQL). This is my first real foray into OOP and have been brought to a stretching halt. I've been looking at my files for a over week trying my best to sort out the issue with no luck.

Oddly I have tried using the exercise files directly on my local machine and I'm getting the same error (with my information like database creds and directory names).

Basically my problem is that when I try to upload a photo it gets moved from the temp directory to the images directory but never makes its way to the database. I get the 'database query failed' message when it posts and the photograph table in mysql remains empty. I see where the error is coming from ( inside database.php confirm_query() ) but have no inclination as to what the issue could be. I know I am able to communicate with the database because just before moving onto creating the photograph class/table I was able to add users to the user table in the database.

Below are my files. Im adding the three that I believe relate to this issue but will zip the whole project up and upload it to dropbox as well. Any help/insight would be more than greatly appreciated!!

*please note that I have put the functions from the databaseObject into the photograph class

photo_upload.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../../includes/initialize.php');
if (!$session->is_logged_in()) {
    redirect_to("login.php");
}

$max_file_size = 1048576;   //expressed in bytes
//  10240  = 10kb
// 102400  = 100kb
//1048576  = 1mb
//10485760 = 1mb

   $message = "";
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $photo = new Photograph();
    $photo->caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $photo->attach_file($_FILES['file_upload']);
        if ($photo->save()) {
        //success
        $message = "Photograph uploaded successfully";
    } else {
        //failure
        $message = join("<br>", $photo->errors);
    }
}

include_layout_template('admin_header.php');
?>

<h2>Photo Upload</h2>

<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
    <form action="photo_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"   method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">

    <p><input type="file" name="file_upload"></p>

    <p>Caption: <input type="text" name="caption" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
<?php include_layout_template('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

Photograph.php:

```
    <?php
// If it's going to need the database, then it's
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

class Photograph extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name="photographs";
    protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'filename', 'type', 'size', 'caption');
    public $id;
    public $filename;
    public $type;
    public $size;
    public $caption;

    private $temp_path;
    protected $upload_dir="images";
    public $errors=array();

    protected $upload_errors = array(
        // http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        UPLOAD_ERR_OK               => "No errors.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE         => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE        => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL          => "Partial upload.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE          => "No file.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR       => "No temporary directory.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE       => "Can't write to disk.",
        UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION        => "File upload stopped by extension."
);

// Pass in $_FILE(['uploaded_file']) as an argument
public function attach_file($file) {
    // Perform error checking on the form parameters
    if(!$file || empty($file) || !is_array($file)) {
        // error: nothing uploaded or wrong argument usage
        $this->errors[] = "No file was uploaded.";
        return false;
    } elseif($file['error'] != 0) {
        // error: report what PHP says went wrong
        $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors[$file['error']];
        return false;
    } else {
        // Set object attributes to the form parameters.
        $this->temp_path  = $file['tmp_name'];
        $this->filename   = basename($file['name']);
        $this->type       = $file['type'];
        $this->size       = $file['size'];
        // Don't worry about saving anything to the database yet.
        return true;

    }
}

public function save() {
    // A new record won't have an id yet.
    if(isset($this->id)) {
        // Really just to update the caption
        $this->update();
    } else {
        // Make sure there are no errors

        // Can't save if there are pre-existing errors
        if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }

        // Make sure the caption is not too long for the DB
        if(strlen($this->caption) > 255) {
            $this->errors[] = "The caption can only be 255 characters long.";
            return false;
        }

        // Can't save without filename and temp location
        if(empty($this->filename) || empty($this->temp_path)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file location was not available.";
            return false;
        }

        // Determine the target_path
        $target_path = SITE_ROOT .DS. 'public' .DS. $this->upload_dir .DS. $this->filename;

        // Make sure a file doesn't already exist in the target location
        if(file_exists($target_path)) {
            $this->errors[] = "The file {$this->filename} already exists.";
            return false;
        }

        // Attempt to move the file
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->temp_path, $target_path)) {
            // Success
            // Save a corresponding entry to the database
            if($this->create()) {
                // We are done with temp_path, the file isn't there anymore
                unset($this->temp_path);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            // File was not moved.
            $this->errors[] = "The file upload failed, possibly due to incorrect permissions on the upload folder.";
            return false;
        }
    }
}


// Common Database Methods
public static function find_all() {
    return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name);
}

public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}

public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
}

private static function instantiate($record) {
    // Could check that $record exists and is an array
    $object = new self;
    // Simple, long-form approach:
    // $object->id              = $record['id'];
    // $object->username    = $record['username'];
    // $object->password    = $record['password'];
    // $object->first_name = $record['first_name'];
    // $object->last_name   = $record['last_name'];

    // More dynamic, short-form approach:
    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}

private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    // We don't care about the value, we just want to know if the key exists
    // Will return true or false
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $this->attributes());
}

protected function attributes() {
    // return an array of attribute names and their values
    $attributes = array();
    foreach(self::$db_fields as $field) {
        if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
            $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}

protected function sanitized_attributes() {
    global $database;
    $clean_attributes = array();
    // sanitize the values before submitting
    // Note: does not alter the actual value of each attribute
    foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value){
        $clean_attributes[$key] = $database->escape_value($value);
    }
    return $clean_attributes;
}

// replaced with a custom save()
// public function save() {
//   // A new record won't have an id yet.
//   return isset($this->id) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
// }

public function create() {
    global $database;
    // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
    // - INSERT INTO table (key, key) VALUES ('value', 'value')
    // - single-quotes around all values
    // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
    if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function update() {
    global $database;
    // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
    // - UPDATE table SET key='value', key='value' WHERE condition
    // - single-quotes around all values
    // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $attribute_pairs = array();
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
    $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
    $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;
}

public function delete() {
    global $database;
    // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
    // - DELETE FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
    // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
    // - use LIMIT 1
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ".self::$table_name;
    $sql .= " WHERE id=". $database->escape_value($this->id);
    $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
    $database->query($sql);
    return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;

    // NB: After deleting, the instance of User still
    // exists, even though the database entry does not.
    // This can be useful, as in:
    //   echo $user->first_name . " was deleted";
    // but, for example, we can't call $user->update()
    // after calling $user->delete().
    }

}

?>
```

database.php:

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

    //Step #1 open connection
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {//once you create an instance of this class it will automatically create the connection
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    public function open_connection(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        //Test the connection
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){//use errno because error returns an empty string if succesful
            die('Database connection failed: '. mysqli_connect_error().
                '('.mysqli_connect_errno().')');
        }
    }

    //Step #2 preform database query
    public function query($sql){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result){
        if(!$result){ //this is a check to make sure the query worked
            die('Database query failed');
        }
    }

    public function escape_value($string){
        $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
        return $escaped_string;
    }

    //database neutral functions
    //this is our database adapter which is called for mysql
    public function fetch_array($result_set){
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    }

    public function num_rows($result_set) {
        return mysqli_num_rows($result_set);
    }

    public function insert_id(){
        //get the last id inserted over the current connection
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows(){
        return mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }

    //Step #4 close connection
    public function close_connection() {
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();



?>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqdi2dz2mbkuwzz/photo_gallery.zip?dl=0

Comment: What is the error and can you reduce the code to just the error part?

Comment: Add debugging output. Track sql statements beeing executed and print out `mysqli_error($result)` within confirm_query().

Comment: Thanks for response! I tacked mysqli_error to the end of the 'database query failed' message and got: "Database query failed Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1" So I removed the 'id' from the $db_fields array and it uploaded the file to mysql since it is set to auto increment in the DB. Is there a way to keep it? I just don't want it to bite me in the butt later.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging around I have concluded that my problem was not with my code. There was an sql setting that would not allow me to enter and empty string `sqlmode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. Thank you maxhb for pointing me in the right direction!!

What I did end up doing to solve this issue was create a `my.conf` file to change the default settings (im running mysql 5.7.9 on mac osx 10.11 btw). What was weird was that it only worked if I put this file in two locations they are  `.my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with the following text:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```